# Amazon s3 bucket con GoDaddy

Tags: amazon-s3

Tengo un bucket en Amazon s3 para subir imágenes. Lo he asociado a un subdominio que tengo con Go Daddy. Hasta aquí, todo bien.

Tengo tres formas de acceder a cualquier archivo del bucket:

> 1. subdomain.domain.com
> 2. your_bucket_name.s3.amazonaws.com
> 3. s3.amazonaws.com/your_bucket_name

Me gustaría que cuando pusiera las opciones 2 y 3 estas se redirigieran a la opción 1. He probado con Route53, pero no he podido, y lo he intentado un poco a ciegas con GoDaddy, pero sin éxito.

Comment: Utiliza el enlace [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/93190/edit) en tu pregunta para añadir información adicional. El botón Publicar respuesta se debe usar solamente para respuestas completas a la pregunta.También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez puedas hacerlo así. Entra a la consola de S3 y en **Properties** elige la tarjeta **Static web hosting**. Ahi configura tu redirección.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]